# Pull information from a web page that ends in .php

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, nsurlconnection, text-parsing

I need to pull a bunch of data from this website (https://www.bowdoin.edu/apps/mobile/nutrition.php - basically a huge blob of text) and eventually save it into attributes of core data entities.

here's what a block of text from the website might look like (trimmed down)

```
Monday, May 06, 2013|Thorne|Breakfast
Item|Portion|SFA(g)|FATRN(g)|PUFA(g)|MONO(g)|CHOL(mg)|Na(mg)|CHO(g)|TDFB(g)|Sugar(g)|Pro(g)|VTAIU(IU)|VITC(mg)|Ca(mg)|Fe(mg)|KCal|Fat(g)
Oatmeal|2/3  Cup|0.18|0|0.37|0.32|0|261|10.81|1.7|0|2.6|0|0|10.91|0.7|62|1
Pancakes|2 each|0.289|0|0.486|0.486|6|350|33.08|1.5|5.54|2.99|29.98|2.75|72.12|1.03|160|1.47

Monday, May 06, 2013|Thorne|Lunch
Item|Portion|SFA(g)|FATRN(g)|PUFA(g)|MONO(g)|CHOL(mg)|Na(mg)|CHO(g)|TDFB(g)|Sugar(g)|Pro(g)|VT    AIU(IU)|VITC(mg)|Ca(mg)|Fe(mg)|KCal|Fat(g)
Deli Bar  Lunch|portion|4.384|0.003|1.157|2.731|47|735|33.12|2.9|3.5|15.06|807.02|4.91|148.58|3.07|297|11.46
Chilled Fruit S|6 oz portion|0.837|0|0.089|0.359|5|24|15.48|0.6|10.75|1.86|635.11|46.86|109.75|0.53|79|1.42

Monday, May 07, 2013|Thorne|Lunch
Item|Portion|SFA(g)|FATRN(g)|PUFA(g)|MONO(g)|CHOL(mg)|Na(mg)|CHO(g)|TDFB(g)|Sugar(g)|Pro(g)|VT    AIU(IU)|VITC(mg)|Ca(mg)|Fe(mg)|KCal|Fat(g)
Italian Bread|slice|0.245|0.005|0.985|0.486|0|172|10.73|0.7|0.48|1.61|0|0|2.81|0.6|67|1.84
Orange Gelatin |1/2 Cup|0|0|0|0|0|53|17.59|0|0|1.52|0|0|2.74|0.04|74|0
```

Research has pointed me to `NSURLConnection` and `NSString's stringWithContentsOfFile:encoding:error: method`, but I am unsure how to use them.

I guess the main issue is parsing, as I'll figure out the `coredata` stuff after.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Is it possible to change that text format to something common format available like JSON or XML?

Comment: The dev who provided this page to me did it in PHP. It would be a ton easier if they converted it to JSON, but this is what I got. Can you convert to JSON in PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's what I ended up doing:

1) Get the data in the form of an NSString:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.<school>.edu/apps/mobile/nutrition.php"];
NSString* fileContents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

2) Parse through the huge NSString, saving each row as an object in a dictionary, the first entry in the row is the key for the array saved in the row. (haven't yet implemented)